# nodeJs huge array processing throws RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, memory-management

This is part of code to proceed big number of entries ( originally its works with file system and make some operations with files) .  Is there any nice way to bypass the limitation and prevent throwing of *RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*
( As for now it allows me to iterate about 3000 items )

```
var async = require('async')
    , _u = require('underscore')

var tifPreview = function (item, callback) {
    console.log(item)
    return callback();
}

var tifQueue = async.queue(tifPreview, 2)

tifQueue.push(_u.range(0, 5000, 1))
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that you are making to many function calls. Setting the `stack-size` to a higher value will only increase the number of items you can handle, not solve the actual problem.

You are calling the next iteration straight from your function, which makes it a recursive function. It's a bit hard to spot since it's going thru `async`.

This code should work:

```
var tifPreview = function (item, callback) {
  console.log(item);

  // defer the callback
  setImmediate(callback);
}
```

Read more about the `setImmediate` function here:
http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Actually fixes instead of pushing the bottle neck down.

Answer (score 25):

An option could be passing `--max-stack-size` to `node`.

```
node --max-stack-size 32000 app.js
```

For reference, use `node -h`

> `--max-stack-size=val` set max v8 stack size (bytes)

## Update

Even though help prints it as `--max-stack-size`, in `node -v` `v0.10.x`+ you need to use `--stack-size` instead.

```
node --stack-size=32000 app.js
```

Comment: In recent builds, it's actually `--stack-size` even though the help text says otherwise.

Comment: @Nico: with --stack-size=32000 it exits with no error but it stops the execution anyway. From the Node's man page it seems that is --stack_size instead of --stack-size.

Comment: I don't think increasing the stack size is a real solution. It doesn't fix the underlying issue. The code should be re-implemented by using streams or by breaking into multiple sub-processes.