# Does it make sense to say process.nextTick can somewhat help preventing stack overflow?

Tags: node.js

Does it make sense to say process.nextTick can somewhat help preventing stack overflow ? I mean if we are sure we don't want the code to be executed immediately

*Yes ! I placed stack overflow in a question !*

Comment: Why would you prevent Stack Overflow, it's great !

Comment: Oh my! down votes! Care to explain? Down votes are not a shortcut to answering "NO". "No" is still an answer :)

Comment: "preventing stack overflow" is a sensitive pharse :)) +1 anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you definitely can't say that. For example:

```
(function stuff () {
  process.nextTick(stuff)
}())
```

will lead to `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Comment: What kinds of non-recursive stack overflows you want to prevent?

Comment: When you have a lot of callbacks (most of which are not really async)

Comment: And how can that cause stack overflow? may be you have an example of code?

Comment: Example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243945/nodejs-huge-array-processing-throws-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Comment: FOund my answer here. Thanks anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220710/understanding-the-node-js-event-queue-and-process-nexttick

Comment: Oh, it's basically the same - infinite recursion. `setImmediate` helps. The problem is that `process.nextTick` is not actually async